# input() blocks other python processes in Windows 8 (python 3.3)

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, input, python-3.x

Working on a multi-threaded cross-platform python3.3 application I came across some weird behavior I was not expecting and am not sure is expected. The issue is on Windows 8 calling the `input()` method in one thread blocks other threads until it completes. I have tested the below example script on three Linux, two Windows 7 and one Windows 8 computers and this behavior is only observed on the Windows 8 computer. Is this expected behavior for Windows 8?

test.py:

```
import subprocess, threading, time

def ui():
    i = input("-->")
    print(i)

def loop():
    i = 0
    f = 'sky.{}'.format(i)
    p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'copy.py', 'sky1', f])
    t = time.time()
    while time.time() < t+15:
        if p.poll() != None:
            print(i)
            time.sleep(3)
            i+=1
            f = 'sky.{}'.format(i)
            p = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'copy.py', 'sky1', f])
    p.terminate()
    p.wait()

def start():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=ui)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=loop)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    return t2

t2 = start()
t2.join()
print('done')
```

copy.py:

```
import shutil
import sys

src = sys.argv[1]
dst = sys.argv[2]

print('Copying \'{0}\' to \'{1}\''.format(src, dst))
shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

Update:
While trying out one of the suggestions I realized that I rushed to a conclusion missing something obvious. I apologize for getting off to a false start.

As Schollii suggested just using threads (no subprocess or python files) results in all threads making forward progress so the problem actually is using `input()` in one python process will cause other python processes to block/not run (I do not know exactly what is going on). Furthermore, it appears to be just python processes that are affected. If I use the same code shown above (with some modifications) to execute non-python executables with subprocess.Popen they will run as expected.

To summarize:

- Using subprocess to execute non-python executable: works as expected with and without any calls to `input()`.
- Using subprocess to execute python executable: created processes appear to not run if a a call to `input()` is made in the original process.
- Use subprocess to create python processes with a call to `input()` in a new process and not the original process: A call to `input()` blocks all python processes spawned by the 'main' process.

Side Note: I do not have Windows 8 platform so debugging/tests can be a little slow.

Comment: Does it help if you rename your `copy.py` script to something else?   When I start up the Python interpreter and type `import shutil` I get an error because Python trips over the `copy.py` file in my local folder.

Comment: @LukeWoodward: I suspect it should be `copy_loop.py`.

Comment: You could build python from source on Win 8, run python test.py from the debugger, then pause the run via the debugger when everything blocks, see what the other threads are blocked on. You might be able to find out why the blocking call blocks on 8 but not on 7.

Comment: The other question is whether this still happens if you only use threading but not subprocess: remove code, abandon copy.py, pare down test.py so you just have two threads, one doing input, do you get same behavior? Then re-introduce pieces of code until you see the behavior again. Sorry no easy answer!

Comment: @EthanFurman: I suspect not, given that the questioner has now edited the question to replace `'copy_loop.py'` with `'copy.py'`.

Comment: I have not had any problems using either copy.py or copy_loop.py; the edit was more to remove obvious error than anything.
I edited the main post again with an actual update on the behavior so take a gander if you are still interested.

Comment: I am wondering if the problem you are seeing is related to the changes in Python versions to how file handles are or are not "copied" between processes and thread and the locking of them (and the buffers of them). I believe stdin, stdout, stderr are file handles 0,1 and 2 which were tied to DOS device CON: (and that there are a few other predefined file handles; 3 through 9 which use to be associated with other DOS devices COM0-COM3, LPT1,2 etc, ... I think)

Answer (score 1):

Because there are several problems with `input` in *Python 3.0-3.2* this method has been impacted with few changes.

It's possible that we have a new bug again.

Can you try the following variant, which is `raw_input()` "back port" (which was avaiable in *Python 2.x*):

```
...
i = eval(input("-->"))
...
```

Comment: I don't think this is pertinent to the question. First, you're showing an equivalent to Python 2.x's `input()` to be used with Python 3.x, not a `raw_input()` backport. Python 3's `input()` *is* Python 2's `raw_input()` (more or less). Second, how would wrapping a blocking function in another call stop it from blocking?

Answer (score 1):

It's a very good problem to work with,

since you are dependent with `input()` method, which, usually needs the console input,

since you have threads, all the threads are trying to communicate with the console,

So, I advice you to use either `Producer-Consumer` concept or define all your inputs to a text file and pass the text file to the program.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? In my program only one call to input() (in a thread of the main process) is made by all the python processes and threads. A non-blocking input method would probably fix the issue, but that is merely going around the problem.